# The attribute 'action' may not appear in tag 'FORM [method=POST]' while making AMP pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have a website in asp.net and I am working on creating AMP pages at `http://mywebsite.com/amp/......`

I was able to make all the necessary changes for AMP except the following error.

> The attribute 'action' may not appear in tag 'FORM [method=POST]'

the Form tag in my website looks like this

```
<form name="form1" method="post" id="form1">
```

AMP tutorial suggest to use `action-xhr=/default.aspx` instead of `action="default.aspx`

here is the source: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/

Now, the thing is how to remove action attribute and add `action-xhr` attribute in asp.net.

I tried following code in cs file but no luck.

```
this.Page.Form.Attributes.Remove("action");
```

Please note `JavaScript` and `jQuery` are not allowed in AMP

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx), where it talks about an `ActionlessForm`.  You basically inherit `HtmlForm`, and replace the form tag on the aspx page with your new control.  You'll have to replace a bit of code like they suggest with the following:

```
base.Attributes.Remove("action");
writer.WriteAttribute("action-xhr", this.Action);
```

Worked like a charm for me.  You may need to replace `this.Action` with `this.Page.Request.Path`, and you may find that you need to also add a `target` attribute, but this will definitely put you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in the head tag (this will make your `form` to [amp-form](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/?format=websites)):

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
```

Now, your form can have `action-xhr` attribute.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action-xhr="__url__">
```

and